# Arabic Walla Recordings

Tags: film-sound-design, walla, foreign

Am looking for some Arabic walla. Conversations as well as yelling/screaming (as if under attack). Any libraries have these available?

Comment: DigiFX or some of the BBC libraries might - they tend to be more diverse, worldly libraries in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

I live in Dubai so might be able to find some for you.
Is there anything specific that you need. If I don't have it I might be able to get it for you.

Let me know.